# How to fix "Missing class properties transform"

Tags: typescript, class, babeljs

My project is built by myself, and if I use class syntax in the ts file, the following error will be reported

```
class Socket {
    ws: null | WebSocket = null; // Error here：Missing class properties transform.

    constructor(url: string, sub?: DefaultObject) {
        this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
    }
}
```

I also tried to install some babel module plugins to solve it, but it didn't work.

```json
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "modules": false
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
            {
                "useESModules": true
            }
        ],
        "@babel/plugin-transform-classes",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
    ]
}
```

My package.json

```json
"devDependencies":{
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.13.5",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "^7.13.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
        "@commitlint/cli": "^11.0.0",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^11.0.0",
        "@types/chrome": "^0.0.128",
        "@types/color": "^3.0.1",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
        "@types/pako": "^1.0.1",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
        "@types/requestidlecallback": "^0.3.1",
        "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.7",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.12.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.12.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.1",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
}
```

If presets in babelrc is configured to es2015/stage-0, there will be other errors.

So what can I do to fix this error, or use function and prototype instead of class.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Just been running into the same issue myself :/